# iOS UIPageViewController - Attempt to present X on Y whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios6, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

I have multiple VC and it looks like , [image: http://imgur.com/WcpZIBi]

What happens is:

1. Data loads in Splash View Controller
2. After loading modal segue from Splash View Controller to Root View Controller
3. Root View Controller is from the Apple's example UIPageViewController which loads bunch of pages (Data View Controller)
4. From those pages there is modal segue to Other View Controller
5. From Other View Controller, it is possible to go back to Splash View Controller to load more data

Do I need to provide some other parameters along with this to get rid of the warning?

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"splashToRoot" sender:self];
```